# QGIS how to access to constrained clustering plugin?

Tags: qgis, clustering

QGIS how to access to constrained clustering plugin? I have downloaded the plugin but I'm wondering where to find it?

Answer (score 3):

You can find it under the **Plugins** Menu.
  [image]